# WordPress plugins translation

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to translate plugin which I made, the thing is I don't want to translate other plugins, when language in my plugin is changed.

I used:

```
add_filter('plugin_locale', 'switch_language', 10, 2);
```

switch_language function load language like EN_en

```
function switch_language() 
{
   $pls_language = get_option('jezik');
   return $pls_language;  
}
```

is it possible to use `add_filter('plugin_locale')` at only one plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'load_my_textdomain');
function load_my_textdomain(){
    $mo_file_path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/lang/'. get_locale() . '.mo';
    load_textdomain('mytranslate', $mo_file_path );
}
```

Only way to skip plugin_locale and load_plugin texdomain is function load_textdomain, wich direct load mo file so, only wanted strings are translated