# Translation files of my plugin are not being loaded or work incorrect

Tags: wordpress, internationalization

I need to translate some parts of text to French.

Things I've tried so far:

1. I created `fr.po` and `fr.mo` files in my plugin's `/languages` directory. I used Poedit for this purpose. I've tried different variants like `fr_FR` - didn't help.
2. I added the following to my plugin's main file along with its name and other information:

```
 * Text Domain:       pluginname
 * Domain Path:       /languages
```

Plugin name does not contain any special characters or underscores/dashes - it's a single word.

3. Also, tried to use `load_plugin_textdomain()` function instead (or even along with) to make this work.
4. Also, tried to add this to my `wp-config.php` file:

```
define ('WPLANG', 'fr_FR');
```

5. Tried to use any combinations of described actions as well.

I have a string to be translated:

```
__('Recently', 'pluginname')
```

The word "Recently" is being displayed correctly but it is not being translated if I change site language. I tried both changing in WP admin panel and adding into config file (mentioned above)

I tried to use `get_locale()` to check if this was actually changed. This returns `'fr_FR'` which is exactly the same with my .po/.mo file names.

**P.S.: ** Checked all these questions and tried all suggested solutions - didn't help:

- [Wordpress - Plugin translation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54016305/wordpress-plugin-translation-not-working)
- [WordPress plugin translation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440929/wordpress-plugin-translation-issue)
- [Wordpress plugins translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27253404/wordpress-plugins-translation)

---

**Update:** `load_plugin_textdomain()` returns false if I try to `var_dump()` result right after function execution.

Comment: It sounds to me that the problem is the filename of your translation files: since you mentioned that your plugin's name is a single word (eg. _Recently_), your files should be named like `recently-fr_FR.mo` an `recently-fr_FR.po`. But all this is a just a guess, without seeing your code we won't be able to know for sure if this is the problem or not.

Comment: Looks like you're right @cabrerahector. I tried to start from scratch using Loco Translate plugin for WP. And it created files that were names just like you said. And it worked. Whereas Poedit didn't ask me for the plugin name (probably, I should set it somewhere manually...) and created fr.po/fr.mo files by default. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the problem was in the names of files. Other than locale name it should also consist of the plugin name, e.g. `pluginname-fr_FR.po/pluginname-fr_FR.mo` for my case. Yes, this is described in the codex, I should read this more attentively :)

Comment: Thank you It works but instead of name you mostly need to use domain name or plugin id.